# Static and Dynamic, Major/Minor Support and Resistance in Stock Trading/Investing

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, technical-analysis

I was reading a short article [the article is here](http://www.sidewaysmarkets.com/2011/08/major-vs-minor-support-and-resistance.html). The author talks about Static and Dynamic support and resistance. While I understand the concept of support and resistance (also to an extent major and minor ones). What is actually a Dynamic support/resistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply static support or resistance levels are ones that do not change with time. Two examples include horizontal lines and trend lines.

Dynamic support or resistance levels are ones that change with time. A common example of a dynamic support/resistance are Moving Averages.